# Морфемный разбор имён собственных

Tags: морфология

Москва, Джон — тут корни **Москв** и **Джон**. А как быть с фамилией Водовозов? Тут какой корень? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Два корня: вод- и -воз-. Фамилия образована от сложного слова *водовоз*, в котром два корня.

Answer (score 0):

В именах собственных корень обычно не выделяется, ограничиваются основой. Основа тут — водовоз. Вот в ней-то можно вычленить два корня.

Comment: Производящая основа "водовоз", а производная "водовозов" . Водо-о-воз-ов- (-ов- суффикс, окончание нулевое)

Comment: Если угодно - производящая. При исследовании фамилий это обычно не оговаривается. Основа - слово, от которого образована фамилия. Обычно - имя нарицательное, от которого фамилия образуется опосредовано через прозвище.